# Where does Phasmophobia store save files?

Tags: phasmophobia

I just changed computers and well, oops, my Phasmophobia progress seems to have resetted to Level 1, 0$.

I do play on 2 different computers, and it seems to point that weirdly, in phasmophobia, the savefile is stored on the computer playing, and not the cloud. (Changing steam accounts also keeps progress, which also points me in that direction)

So if the savefile is on the computer, where is it? So I can pull it from my old computer, put it on the new, and keep my progress?

If not, how can I get back my progress from my old computer to the new?

Comment: Interestingly, I just launched Phasmophobia for the first time on my new computer today and Steam Cloud successfully restored my progress. I would turn *off* Steam Cloud on the computer with progress so that it doesn't get reset via the Cloud, and I'll take a look at where that save lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phasmophobia save data is stored in a fairly small .txt file in your local AppData:

```
%AppData%\..\LocalLow\Kinetic Games\Phasmophobia\saveData.txt
```

This file alone stores all of the save data, and synchronizes via Steam Cloud as of the time of writing.